# Why Main method dosent see public method from the same package?

Tags: oop, program-entry-point

Why `Main` `method()` dosent see `public` `method()` from the same package?

Class and method main:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = new Class();
        c. // dosent see public method1(), when Class c is called.  
    }
  }
```

Class c:

```
public class C {


    public static void method1(){
        //logic
         method2()
         method3()
    }

    private static void method2(){
       //logic
        }
    }

    private static void method3(){
     //logic
        }
    }
}
```

Method `main` and `Class c` locate in the same package, why method `Main` dosent see `public` method from the same package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class c contains `static` content. `method1()` is `static` method. Thats why.